# how can I get Identity UserID in the controller right after a successful login result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using Identity v2 and MVC 5 for external login.

In my external login callback function, I log the user in with

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

then there is a switch for the `result`, and I need to access the user's ID in the `success` case, but `User.Identity.GetUserId();` gives me null here.

How can I access the User's ID in this case?

Comment: You have to create custom ExternalSignInAsync methiod which will return a model with user Id and success results. Check Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples nuget package for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MVC 5's identity, can't get user name right after logging in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429373/using-mvc-5s-identity-cant-get-user-name-right-after-logging-in)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To get claims data and other information about the signed in identity *immediately* upon a successful login, without going to the database, just access `signinManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity`.

For instance,

`switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        var userId = signinManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant
.Identity.GetUserId();
// ...`

You can also see it being used in [this other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749483/transforming-modifying-claims-in-asp-net-identity-2/32062245#32062245) to add new claims to an identity immediately after login - `AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.AddClaims(freshClaims);`

Comment: This is definitely the easiest solution!

Comment: Thank you - This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Been looking for this for ages. I used:

Dim IDClaim As Claim = signInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(Function(o) o.Type = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
Dim UserID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(IDClaim.Value).  Thanks!

Comment: signInManager.AuthenticationManager doesn't seem to exist anymore in Core 2.2. For a one-liner you can use the answer by @A. Burak Erbora

Answer (score 5):

I use `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` object to keep my user id

And I created a helper class to reach the values in it

```
public class UserHelper
  {
    public static string GetUserId()
    {
      var identity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
      var principal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
      var userId = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
      return userId;
    }
    public static string GetUserName()
    {
      var identity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
      var principal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
      var name = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
      return name;
    }
    public static string GetUserMail()
    {
      var identity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
      var principal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
      var mail = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
      return mail;
    }
  }
```

and I call it with

```
var user = UserHelper.GetUserId();
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found **one** way; I can get it via:

```
var userID = UserManager.FindByEmail(loginInfo.Email).Id;
```

But, I don't think this is the best solution since it seems like I hit the DB with two queries. Can Anyone offer a better solution?

Comment: Not a good way. You dont go to the database for UserID.UserId,email  already exists in identity claims.

Comment: @Serdar Çatalpınar: Exactly my point in asking for a better way. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code.

> Add function to ApplicationSignInManager class in Identity.Config.cs

```
 public override Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser)
 {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };
            this.AuthenticationManager.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
            return base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser);
}
```

> Try ths code

```
private ClaimsPrincipal GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
            if (context == null)
                return null;

            if (context.Authentication == null || context.Authentication.User == null)
                return null;

            return context.Authentication.User;
        }
        private string GetUserId()
        {
            var user = GetCurrentUser();
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (claim == null)
                return null;

            return claim.Value;
        }

        private string GetUserEmail()
        {
            var user = GetCurrentUser();
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
            if (claim == null)
                return null;

            return claim.Value;
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately I was too quick to accept this. Whatever I do, Identity.GetUserId<T>(); doesn't give me anything but null right after a login success. My guess is that it waits for a certain stage in the login process to work.

Comment: Problem seems to be thatwhen the signinmanager's signin method is invoked and returns a success result, it does not update the identity user object to be authenticated. Any idea how I can enforce it to be updated there?

Comment: you can try in the above code. I changed code lines.

Comment: Great, I had a feeling I could use the built in claim system for this, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

In dotnet 5 i follow the context after logged in with SignInManager

```
 var result =
            await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var userId = _signInManager.UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault()?.Id; }
```